# Getting stack of invoked methods in java

Tags: java, debugging

i need to know which methods were invoked one by one in code. Simple step-by-step debugging doesn't help (need too much time). How can i do this? It would be really great do this without changes of code and saving result in file.

Comment: Please check this one : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3256369/navigating-java-call-stack-in-eclipse/3256406#3256406

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it seems that maybe you don't want to check the stack tree, just the order, you could check out [BTrace](http://kenai.com/projects/btrace) or [Adding logging with Java agent](http://www.slf4j.org/extensions.html#javaagent).

Answer (score 1):

Before your program finishes, you could `Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace();` and then print each of those elements. A stack trace shows you the order of execution in your thread.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a cross-cutting concern, especially when you talk about not changing existing code.

AspectJ is available to do this work for you using pointcuts.

http://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/released/progguide/starting-aspectj.html

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean you want to log *every* method call that occurs in your program? If so, have a look at AspectJ - there's an example [here](http://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/released/progguide/starting-development.html) which logs particular methods, but you can easily adapt it to cover all methods.

Answer (score 0):

What about when you catch a Exception you can try to use printStackTrace() function to dump out what has been invoked.

```
try{
     //Your code
}
catch(Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Run your code in debug mode, you'll be able to set breakpoints to pause the execution, proceed line by line, inspect variables, etc.. Basically all the IDEs have debug mode.